# Creating Multiple objects once user sign-up (Social Network using OOP)

Tags: python, oop

I am a beginner learning Python (Python 2.7) and I am trying to create a Social Network with it.

Say: I have 9 Classes, namely:

1) Tag

2) Comment

3) Post

4) Profile

5) ProfileInfo

6) Newsfeed

7) Friendlist

8) Notification

9) System # Contains lists of users' ID | Has two functions: SignUp and SignIn

```
SNS_System = System()
SNS_System.signUp()
```

How can I make the program create the other 8 objects once the `SNS_System.signUP()` has been called?
What I want to happen is that I want to assign those 8 objects to a username that was recently created.

Example: If the new user's username is `Peter`, then I want

```
Peter_Comment = Comment()
Peter_Tag = Tag()
Peter_Post = Post()
...... #until
Peter_Notification = Notification()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand well what you want to achieve. I feel you need (or you have it already) a User class that you can instantiate passing it a user_name. Then you can implement your signUp() method like bellow.

```
class System:
    def signUp(self, user_name):
        user = User(user_name)
        user.comment = Comment()
        user.tag = Tag()
        ...
```

Is my answer in the right direction?